# Excel Data Validation Source

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

I've tried searching, but maybe just haven't found the right combination of key words and have been unable to find a solution.

What i'm trying to do in Excel is generate a dynamic validation list based on a key value entered in another cell.

I have 3 worksheets: WSName(Columns)

1. Log (Buildings, Floors)
2. Buildings (BuildingId, BuildingName)
3. Floors (FloorId, BuildingId, FloorName)

I have created a named range for all my building ids called "BuildingIds"

I have created separate named ranges for all floors by building called "Floor#BuildingId#"

What I want is, when a Building is selected in the Log worksheet, the Floor list gets dynamically populated with the available floors for that building from the Floors worksheet.

My thought was in the Data Validation Source I should be able to do this:

```
=INDIRECT("Floors"&$A$2)
```

And it partially works, but always returns the same floors list because $A$2 isn't dynamic depending on the row it's in, so I need $A$2 to use the value from the current row.

This returns the value of the selected building that I want for the current row:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())
```

But when I try:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Floor","A"&ROW()))
```

OR

```
=CONCATENATE("Floor",INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))
```

I get an error.

Can you help me with this formula please?! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use incorrect syntax - that's how manual link looks like:

```
='Sheet 1'!A1
```

Add exclamation and `'` and you're done. The rest seems fine for me)

Comment: Thanks Peter, but i'm confused how to concatenate that with "Floor"?
=CONCATENATE("Floor",'Sheet 1'!A1)

Comment: @JohnSadler it's a sample pal) You don't need it for your solution - use "Floor!" as an argument. `'` is required when sheet has spaces in the name.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain myself clearly though. There are multiple named ranges in the Floor worksheet. One for each building. They are named "Floor"&BuildingId. On my Log Worksheet in the Data Validation Source, I need the formula to be "Floor"&(the selected building id for that row). I see how 'Floor!' referenced my Floor worksheet, but not how it references a specific named range in that worksheet.

Comment: @JohnSadler Please provide several names of named ranges to be more specific: in general, if range is defined at **WORKBOOK** level, it may be referenced directly, without including the name of sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've got this working, I simply set the Data Validation Source to:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Floors",A2))
```

Then when the formula was copied over the entire column, the A2 updated to the current row as expected.

@Peter L. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help buddy) the best way to say thank you here - is to upvote / accept the answer: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)